# What are the differences and performances characteristics of Perl CGI and Catalyst?

Tags: performance, perl, cgi, catalyst

I have both used Perl CGI and Catalyst. I know Catalyst is better than Perl CGI. I know the difference is that Catalyst has better URL handling. But what other differences are there?

Also, how does the performance of an application change if either Catalyst or CGI Perl is used, and why? Source with some real world examples, if you have come across.

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question but you might want to look at Dancer. Dancer is a lightweight MVC web framework for perl, I find it much more friendly to use than Catalyst. http://perldancer.org/

Comment: @mttrb - I don't have any knowledge on `Dancer` but Is it that,`Dancer` best suited for small application or if I want application in less time?.

Comment: I found Dancer much simpler and easier to configure and use than Catalyst.  Most of the stuff I've been doing with it recently has been small to medium sized web apps and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing CGI.pm to Catalyst is like comparing a small laptop computer to a complete office environment.  A laptop is great, bu a home office, has a desk, a chair, printers, maybe a fax machine, scanners, staplers, filing cabinets, pens, paper, and so on.

CGI.pm is for parsing query strings, form data, handling cookies, some basic HTTP handling, maybe some quick and dirty HTML generation, but not much more. That's all you get and that's OK because it's all it's designed to do. In fact, including the HTML generating functions was probably a mistake.

Catalyst, is a complete Web framework designed to make it easy to organize and create Web sites. Here's where the models go, here's where the controllers go, here's where the views go ... and, oh yeah, handling Web requests, cookies, HTTP, sessions, authentication, route dispatching, it has a built-in development server, and so on. It's so far beyond CGI that comparing them doesn't make sense.

If Catalyst seems like overkill for you, I strongly recommend that you check out [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/).

Comment: @Ovid- How about performance?Which one would be faster considering a simple application?.

Comment: drt, your question is a type error, and that is why Ovid isn't answering it.  What is faster: a laptop, or an office?

Answer (score 1):

Well I assume you are talking about CGI::Application not CGI.pm vs Catalyst.

Your application performance is going to depend on what you do with the framework of course and if you can use caching (in which case they are both really fast).

Have a look at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=645497 for more info. Don't let the date scare you, things have not changed that much.

CGI is simple, it covers the basics and you can learn it really quickly.

Catalyst tries to be your faithful assistant and expects you to be loyal and get to know it well.  It can automate a lot of things while still giving you flexibility.  It does use a lot of libraries but it does not, in my opinion, seem to slow it down.  Your hardware and requirements will vary from mine though.

For quick projects I use CGI, for more complex systems I use Catalyst.  It really depends on your project.

Comment: How about In case of CGI.pm vs Catalyst ?

Comment: CGI.pm is mostly for reading and formatting responses over cgi.  You can generate html, read parameters, set sessions.  Back in the day it was a big improvement over doing all that yourself but there is no sense of an application.  You role your own (or use cpan!) on everything else.